# math: scale coordinate system so that certain points get integer coordinates

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

this is more a mathematical problem. nonethelesse i am looking for the algorithm in pseudocode to solve it.

**given is a one dimensional coordinate system, with a number of points. the coordinates of the points may be in floating point.**

**now i am looking for a factor that scales this coordinate system, so that all points are on fixed number (i.e. integer coordinate)**

if i am not mistaken, there should be a solution for this problem as long as the number of points is not infinite.

if i am wrong and there is no analytical solution for this problem, i am interested in an algorithm that approximates the solution as close as possible. (i.e. the coordinates will look like 15.0001)

if you are interested for the concrete problem:
i would like to overcome the well known pixelsnapping problem in adobe flash, which cuts of half-pixels at the border of bitmaps if the whole stage is scaled. i would like to find out an ideal scaling factor for the stage which makes my bitmaps being placed on whole (screen-)pixel coordinates.

since i am placing two bitmaps on the stage, the number of points will be 4 in each direction (x,y).

thanks!

Comment: There's no general solution, e.g., irrational numbers.

Comment: @Jaime Pardos: But irrationals aren't representable as (finite) floats, which is what he seems to have. @OP: A general, but in practice probably stupid, solution would be to represent the floats as fractions of integers up to a desired precision. Then your scale factor is the product of all the denominators.

Comment: thanks, yes let's exclude irrational numbers for this problem

Answer (score 6):

As suggested, you have to convert your floating point numbers to rational ones. Fix a tolerance epsilon, and for each coordinate, find its *best rational approximation* within epsilon.

An algorithm and definitions is outlined [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) in [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_within_an_interval).

Once you have converted all the coordinates into rational numbers, the scaling is given by the least common multiple of the denominators.

Note that this latter number can become quite huge, so you may want to experiment with epsilon so that to control the denominators.

Answer (score 1):

My own inclination, if I were in your situation, would be to use rational numbers not with floating point.
And the algorithms you are looking for is finding the lowest common denominator.

Comment: thanks, but that is not possible, since flash is introducing flotaing point coordinates as soon as the stage is scaled.

Comment: Floating point numbers _are_ by their very nature rational. Although it may not be practical to utilise the full precision range they allow.

Comment: You can look at your float pointing number as a rational number (BTW it is a rational number).

Answer (score 1):

A floating point number is an integer, multiplied by a power of two (the power might be negative).

So, find the largest necessary power of two among your inputs, and that gives you a scale factor that will work. The power of two isn't just -1 times the exponent of the float, it's a few more than that (according to where the least significant 1 bit is in the significand).

It's also optimal, because if `x` times a power of 2 is an odd integer then `x` in its float representation was already in simplest rational form, there's no smaller integer that you can multiply `x` by to get an integer.

Obviously if you have a mixture of large and small values among your input, then the resulting integers will tend to be bigger than 64 bit. So there is an analytical solution, but perhaps not a very good one given what you want to do with the results.

Note that this approach treats floats as being precise representations, which they are not. You may get more sensible results by representing each float as a rational number with smaller denominator (within some defined tolerance), then taking the lowest common multiple of all the denominators.

The problem there though is the approximation process - if the input float is 0.334[*] then I can't in general be sure whether the person who gave it to me really mean 0.334, or whether it's 1/3 with some inaccuracy. I therefore don't know whether to use a scale factor of 3 and say the scaled result is 1, or use a scale factor of 500 and say the scaled result is 167. And that's just with 1 input, never mind a bunch of them.

With 4 inputs and allowed final tolerance of 0.0001, you could perhaps find the 10 closest rationals to each input with a certain maximum denominator, then try 10^4 different possibilities and see whether the resulting scale factor gives you any values that are too far from an integer. Brute force seems nasty, but you might a least be able to bound the search a bit as you go. Also "maximum denominator" might be expressed in terms of the primes present in the factorization, rather than just the number, since if you can find a lot of common factors among them then they'll have a smaller lcm and hence smaller deviation from integers after scaling.

[*] Not that 0.334 is an exact float value, but that sort of thing. Decimal examples are easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about [single precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) numbers, then the number can be expressed like this according to wikipedia:

[image: floating point formula]

From this formula you can deduce that you always get an integer if you multiply by 2<sup>127+23</sup>. (Actually, when `e` is `0` you have to use another formula for the special range of "subnormal" numbers so 2<sup>126+23</sup> is sufficient. See the linked wikipedia article for details.)

To do this in code you will probably need to do some [bit twiddling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation) to extract the factors in the above formula from the bits in the floating point value. And then you will need some kind of support for unlimited size numbers to express the integer result of the scaling (e.g. [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) in .NET). Normal primitive types in most languages/platforms are typically limited to much smaller sizes.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a problem in statistical inference combined with noise reduction. This is the method I'm going to try out soon. I'm assuming you're trying to get a regularly spaced 2-D grid but a similar method could work on a regularly spaced grid of 3 or more dimensions.

First tabulate all the differences and note that (dx,dy) and (-dx,-dy) denote the same displacement, so there's an equivalence relation. Group those differenecs that are within a pre-assigned threshold (epsilon) of one another. Epsilon should be large enough to capture measurement errors due to random noise or lack of image resolution, but small enough not to accidentally combine clusters.

Sort the clusters by their average size (dr = root(dx^2 + dy^2)).

If the original grid was, indeed, regularly spaced and generated by two independent basis vectors, then the two smallest *linearly independent* clusters will indicate so. The smallest cluster is the one centered on (0, 0). The next smallest cluster (dx0, dy0) has the first basis vector up to +/- sign (-dx0, -dy0) denotes the same displacement, recall.

The next smallest clusters may be linearly dependent on this (up to the threshold epsilon) by virtue of being multiples of (dx0, dy0). Find the smallest cluster which is NOT a multiple of (dx0, dy0). Call this (dx1, dy1).

Now you have enough to tag the original vectors. Group the vector, by increasing lexicographic order (x,y) > (x',y') if x > x' or x = x' and y > y'. Take the smallest (x0,y0) and assign the integer (0, 0) to it. Take all the others (x,y) and find the decomposition (x,y) = (x0,y0) + M0(x,y) (dx0, dy0) + M1(x,y) (dx1,dy1) and assign it the integers (m0(x,y),m1(x,y)) = (round(M0), round(M1)).

Now do a least-squares fit of the integers to the vectors to the equations (x,y) = (ux,uy) m0(x,y) (u0x,u0y) + m1(x,y) (u1x,u1y)
to find (ux,uy), (u0x,u0y) and (u1x,u1y). This identifies the grid.

Test this match to determine whether or not all the points are within a given threshold of this fit (maybe using the same threshold epsilon for this purpose).

The 1-D version of this same routine should also work in 1 dimension on a spectrograph to identify the fundamental frequency in a voice print. Only in this case, the assumed value for ux (which replaces (ux,uy)) is just 0 and one is only looking for a fit to the homogeneous equation x = m0(x) u0x.